# dataframe group by for all columns in new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new dataframe with the values grouped by each column header [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlen0.png)
this is the dataset i'm working with.

I essentially want a new dataframe which sums the occurences of 1 and 0 for each feature (chocolate, fruity etc)

i tried this code with the groupby and sort function
`

```
chocolate = data.groupby(["chocolate"]).size()
bar = data.groupby(["bar"]).size()
hard = data.groupby(["hard"]).size()
display(chocolate,bar, hard)
```

`
but this only gives me the sum per feature

this is the end result i want to become
[end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrW31.png)

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example _as text_ (not image) and the exact expected output ?

Comment: Not sure if I'm following you, but if you want to sum ones or zeros on a column is as simple as: pd["col"].sum() if there's only ones and zeros on the given column,   or (pd["col"] == value).sum()

Comment: Please provide dataset in text format. It is difficult to reproduce the problem with image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```py
res = (
    data
    .drop(columns="competitorname")
    .melt().value_counts()
    .unstack()
    .fillna(0).astype("int").T
)
```

- Eliminate the columns that aren't relevant (I've only seen `competitorname`, but there could be more).
- `.melt` the dataframe. The result has 2 columns, one with the column names, and another with the resp. `0`/`1` values.
- Now `.value_counts` gives you a series that essentially contains what you are looking for.
- Then you just have to `.unstack` the first index level (column names) and transpose the dataframe.

Example:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "competitorname": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "chocolate": [1, 0, 0], "bar": [1, 0, 1], "hard": [1, 1, 1]
})
```

```
  competitorname  chocolate  bar  hard
0              A          1    1     1
1              B          0    0     1
2              C          0    1     1
```

Result:

```
variable  bar  chocolate  hard
value                         
0           1          2     0
1           2          1     3
```

Alternative with `.pivot_table`:

```py
res = (
    data
    .drop(columns="competitorname")
    .melt().value_counts().to_frame()
    .pivot_table(index="value", columns="variable", fill_value=0)
    .droplevel(0, axis=1)
)
```

PS: Please don't post images, provide a litte example (like here) that encapsulates your problem.